# Finding a basis for subsets of the polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $U,W$ subsets of the real vector space of polynomials
$$
U=\{p\in\Bbb R[X] : p'(0)=0\}\\
W=\{p\in\Bbb R[X] : p(0)=0\}
$$
find basis $B, C$ for $U, W$ respectively.

my solution was $B = \{0, 1, 0,..., 0\}$ and $C = \emptyset$.

but I have a feeling i'm wrong here... would like some directions.

Comment: When you write $C=\emptyset$, are you saying  you believe that there are no non-zero polynomials of degree $≤n$ that vanish at $0$?  And what might $B=\{0,1,0,0,\cdots,0\}$ mean?

Comment: 1) what is the dimension of the real vector space? 2) what do elements in that real vector space look like? 3) compute $p’(0)$, what do you see? How many ‘degrees of freedom’ do you still have if $p$ has to satisfy the condition of $U$? Same argument for the other subspace.

Comment: okay so I'm definitely in the wrong here.
it seems that polynomials where the coefficient of X^1 is 0 satisfies the conditions for U, and polynomials where the constant term is 0 satisfices the conditions for W.
so would it be correct to say that:
B = {1,0,X^2,X^3,...,X^n}
C = {0,X,X^2,X^3,...,X^n}

Comment: @Roy almost. take the $0$ vector out of the sets. The $0$ vector is not a part of a basis as it immediatly makes the set linearly dependent. I just saw your comment after posting my answer but you basically already got it.

Comment: [By the way, here is a tutorial how to properly type math on this site.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: okay, thank you I appreciate everyones help. I'll look into formatting also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to think of a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ as an $(n+1)$-tuple, i.e.
we identify
$$
p(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k
$$
with $(a_0,a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. This makes it obvious that
$$
V=\{p\in\Bbb R[X] : \deg(p) \leq n\}\ \cong\ \{(a_0, \ldots, a_n) : a_i \in \Bbb R\} = \Bbb R^{n+1}
$$
is a vectorspace of dimension $(n+1)$ with basis $\{(1,0,\ldots, 0), (0,1,0,\ldots, 0), \ldots, (0,\ldots, 0, 1)\}$ which correponds to $\{1,X,X^2,\ldots,X^n\}$.

Now look at the condition $p(0)=0$. Try to grasp what happens to the tuples, espacially which basis elements we can keep.

> Now $p(0)=0$ means $0=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k 0^k = a_0$ so \begin{align*} W=\{p\in V : p(0)=0\} = \{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k : a_0 = 0\} \cong \{(0,a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \Bbb R^{n+1}\} \end{align*} so a basis is given by $\{(0,1,0,\ldots, 0), \ldots, (0,\ldots,0,1)\}$ which corresponds to $\{X,X^2,\ldots, X^n\}$, hence $\dim W = n$.

For $p'(0)=0$ try a similar approach.

> For $p'(0)=0$ we conclude \begin{align*} 0 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k 0^{k-1} = a_1 \end{align*} so \begin{align*} U = \{p\in V : p'(0)=0\} \cong \{(a_0, 0, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \Bbb R^{n+1}\} \end{align*} and a basis for that is given by $\{1,X^2, X^3, \ldots, X^n\}$, so $\dim U = n$.

Comment: would it be correct to say that a linear map from U to W is isomorphic, since their dimensions are equal?

Comment: @Roy Not necesarrily. Between vector spaces of equal dimension you can always find an isomorphism. But not every linear map from $U$ to $W$ is a bijection. Take for example the constant map $U\to W, p\mapsto X$. This is neither injective nor surjective. You can easily find an isomorphism of the spaces by defining a map that maps the $i$-th element in $B$ to the $i$-th element in $C$, where $B,C$ are the bases of $U,W$ respectively and by $i$-th element I means with respect to some arbitrary order on the elements (for example the order in which I wrote them down).

Comment: got it, again thanks a lot for your help.
last question about this, how would i go about calculating dim(U $\cap$ W)?

I know that dim(U $\cap$ W) = dim(U) + dim(W) - dim(U + W), but i cant figure out how to find dim(U + W).

Comment: @Roy Note that $\{X,X^2,\ldots,X^n\} \subseteq W \subseteq U+W$. Furthermore $1\in U \subseteq U+W$. Thus $U+W$ contains the basis of $V$ and therefore $V\subseteq U+W$. But trivially $U+W\subseteq V$ as they are both subspaces.

Comment: Alternativly you could also look at what polynomials are contained in $U\cap W$. All polynomials in $W$ have $a_0=0$ and all polynomials in $U$ have $a_1=0$. So every polynomial in $U\cap W$ satisfies $a_0=a_1=0$ where the other $n-1$ coefficients are arbitrary. This should make it obvious that the dimension is $\dim(U\cap W)=n-1$.